# Adding Session State Provider using Azure KeyVault for the connection string

Tags: azure, caching, redis, session-state-provider

Currently I am trying to add MS Session State Provider in my project:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider

The settings are like this:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
      <providers>
        <!-- For more details check https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki -->
        <!-- Either use 'connectionString' OR 'settingsClassName' and 'settingsMethodName' OR use 'host','port','accessKey','ssl','connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds' and 'operationTimeoutInMilliseconds'. -->
        <!-- 'throwOnError','retryTimeoutInMilliseconds','databaseId' and 'applicationName' can be used with both options. -->
        <!--
          <add name="MySessionStateStore" 
            host = "127.0.0.1" [String]
            port = "" [number]
            accessKey = "" [String]
            ssl = "false" [true|false]
            throwOnError = "true" [true|false]
            retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
            databaseId = "0" [number]
            applicationName = "" [String]
            connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
            operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000" [number]
            connectionString = "<Valid StackExchange.Redis connection string>" [String]
            settingsClassName = "<Assembly qualified class name that contains settings method specified below. Which basically return 'connectionString' value>" [String]
            settingsMethodName = "<Settings method should be defined in settingsClass. It should be public, static, does not take any parameters and should have a return type of 'String', which is basically 'connectionString' value.>" [String]
            loggingClassName = "<Assembly qualified class name that contains logging method specified below>" [String]
            loggingMethodName = "<Logging method should be defined in loggingClass. It should be public, static, does not take any parameters and should have a return type of System.IO.TextWriter.>" [String]
            redisSerializerType = "<Assembly qualified class name that implements Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer>" [String]
          />
        -->
        <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="" accessKey="" ssl="true" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

However, we don't want to expose our connection string with access key in our web.config file. We are using Azure KeyVault for this.

Is there any way I can use Azure KeyVault with Session State Provider?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settingsClassName and settingsMethodName settings can be used to provide a Class and method that return the connection string. This method that you define can turn around to KeyVault and return the required connection string.

[How to use configuration parameters of Session State Provider and Output Cache Provider](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: Good stuff! It seems I have to use both `settingsClassName` and `settingsMethodName`. btw, what does `Assembly qualified class name` mean? Where should I declare my class and method?

Comment: For detail implementation, we can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48566488/3283323